# Смена значения свойства объёкта через переменную в JavaScript

Tags: javascript

Код:

```
function calculator() {
    var target = document.getElementById('calwindow');
    var button = document.getElementById('mybuttons');

    button.onclick = calculate;
    function calculate(e) {

        var calbutton = e.target;
        var buttvalue = calbutton.value;

        if(calbutton.tagName != 'INPUT') return;

        var temp = target.value;

    ...
```

Я писал небольшую программу-калькулятор и столкнулся с тем, что я не могу присвоить значение `target.value` через другую переменную `temp`.

`target.value` -- это свойство объекта на странице, куда я хочу записать значение переменной `buttvalue`.

Если записать `target.value = buttvalue;`, то всё работает корректно, значение присваивается, но через запись `temp = buttvalue;` значение присвоить не удаётся.

Где я допускаю ошибку?
Правильно ли я понимаю, что `temp` является ссылкой на переменную `target.value` и что через него можно управлять ее значением?

Comment: строка вида `var temp = target.value;` просто делает копию значения в переменную temp. И потому не связано с начальным объектом.

Comment: А как в таком случае происходит изменение элемента, после того как мы присваиваем target = document.getElementById('calwindow');, в этом же случае изменения target отражаются на элементе в документе, получается, что такое можно делать только элементами, т.к. они обьекты javascript? И если это так, то как можно коротко записать target.value в коде? Я часто к ней обращаюсь, неужели каждый раз надо пистать target.value?

Comment: С объектами такой фокус пройдет, с простыми типами - нет. Нет в Javascript указателей и ссылок в понимании других языков программирования (то есть они есть, но их использование в некоторых случаях затруднительно).

Comment: Спасибо за ответ, если не затруднит, сможешь подсказать, как можно причесать такой код, я точно уверен, что его можно записать лаконичнее 


  if(calbutton.tagName != 'INPUT') return;
  var temp = target.value;
  if(clear) { 
   target.value = buttvalue;
   clear = false;
   return;
  }
  if(temp == '0') { 
   target.value = buttvalue; 
   return;
   }
  if(buttvalue =='=') {
  var temp2 = target.value.split(' ');

Comment: я не вижу, что здесь можно причесывать. Он работает адекватно?
Единственное, я бы подумал о замене == на [===](http://javascript.ru/comparison-operators)

Comment: Ок, еще раз спасибо за ответы.

Comment: Добавь кусок кода из комметария в пост. :-D блин староват вопросец

Comment: Ему бы еще ответ накатать. Вообще имхо надо казнить таких некроисправляльщиков, за то что забивают тухлыми вопросами поток измененных авторами вопросов, которые все еще требуют ответа. В "текущих" и "без ответа" вопросах из-за таких личностей сложно выловить кого-нибудь, кому еще требуется помощь.

Answer (score 1):

В вашем случае вы присваиваете просто переменной `temp` значение `e.target.value;` и ничего более. Для изменения значения `e.target.value`, очевидно надо присваивать `e.target.value = 'необходимо вам значение';`. Ваш фокус с ссылкой на значение не пройдет, в javascript ссылки передаются на объекты. Если вы часто работаете с каким-то элементом, просто сохраните ссылку на него например `var el = e.target;` и далее уже меняйте значение у объекта `el` например `el.value = 'new value';` Сохранять ссылки на объекты и потом работать с ними в место постоянной выборки элемента в DOM является хорошим тоном.